# Level 9: 8 key presses to go

Tags: vim-adventures

It is a puzzle! I would like to go form `f` to `S` as the picture order in 8 key presses.
[image]

The keyboard I can use is
[image]

Now I can go to `u` with two key presses left as
[image]

How should I do? Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First hint, which will probably be enough: you can use count with <kbd>*</kbd>

For completion sake, full answer hidden below:

> fi3*Fu2*

Comment: Dear @slawek Thank you very much. I find a complicated method to finish the job by using `*` only once LOL

Comment: You could share it here, always nice to see more than one solution.

Comment: no need to hide it: `fi3*Fu2*`

Comment: I don't understand why `9*` does solve it at the end.

Answer (score 2):

This is a stupid method. It consists of Three steps.

1. Let cursor be at the 1-st numbered "f" then press `f` `i` `1` `8` `w` `F` `u` `*` then press `any-key`
2. The cursor is again at the 1-st numbered "f", the purpose is to store the searching for "i" so that we can save one stroke for the next step. For example, We press `f` `i` `5` `h` `h` `l` After this step, the searching for "i" is remembered.
3. Now the cursor is at the 1-st numbered "f" again, then press `;` `1` `8` `w` `F` `u` `2` `n`

For the go back press `1` `3` `B`

Comment: I like the trick of saving one stroke and using `;` instead of `fi` ;)